# Is it possible to bulk edit all my Facebook posts?

Tags: facebook

I am in a situation, where I have to bulk-edit all URLs I have ever posted, preferably with a regular expression. Is that possible?

Comment: Facebook has an API or you could use something like iMacros to script a solution (after paging all the way down on your "activity" page)

Comment: "Bulk update" in what way? There is a tool which will let you change all of your past "Public" posts to "Friends".

Answer (score 2):

Natively via Facebook desktop, no, there is no way to do this.

Using iMacros or any extension based on the number of posts in the bulk can lead you to a rate limit block on your account.

Using the API via a third party application will not work either as third party applications cannot edit posts that did not come from that application.

So, the safest bet is to use the API with a Facebook native application user access token (i.e. a whitelisted Facebook mobile app), using the Facebook native app will ensure

- all posts are received
- lower the risks of rate limit occuring
- be able to edit any post

Within the scope of this site (since programming is off topic) all I can do is point you to references

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/
- https://github.com/jgorset/facepy

Comment: 0

I'm confuse, do that means we need to use 1) some code that use the facebook API which need to be sent through 2) a "whitelisted Facebook mobile app"? If I don't get it, and we need to choose one or the other, what's the quickest/simpliest way to edit old post? (I just want to set all post to public).